# Gulp and FTP : How to transfer only the content of a folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, gulp

Gulp with vinyl ftp : how to specify different directory name?
I am using [vinyl-ftp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl-ftp) with gulp to push my local `dist/` directory to remote production server.

Thing is my local ready-to-production directory name is "`dist`", and I want all of its content to be pushed in a "`www`" directory on the server.

The code is :

```
gulp.task( 'deploy:prod', ['build:dist'], function() {

    var conn = ftp.create( {
        host:     'ftp.website.com',
        user:     'username',
        password: 'password'
    } );

    var globs = ['./dist/**'];

    return gulp.src( globs, {base: '.', buffer: false } )
        .pipe( conn.differentSize( 'www/' ) ) 
        .pipe( conn.dest( 'www/' ) );
} );
```

As you see, I'm trying to get only the content of `dist/` by targeting `'./dist/**'`, but after transfer is done, the path I get is : `/www/dist/`.

One workaround would be to rename my "`dist/`" folder to "`www/`" and then set vinyl ftp's destination to server ROOT, but I'd prefer to keep concerns separated and keep the name "`dist/`" for my local build.

Do you have any ideas on how to have the content of my local `dist/` folder transferred into the remote `www/` folder ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to set your `base` to `./dist/`:

```
return gulp.src( globs, {base: './dist/', buffer: false } )
    .pipe( conn.differentSize( 'www/' ) ) 
    .pipe( conn.dest( 'www/' ) );
```

According to [the API documentation](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/API.md#optionsbase) and some blurred memories this flag's for exactly that case.

Comment: That was it ! You're the boss. Thank you so much !